# Stripping and dropping columns from pandas dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have the following columns in a pandas df:

```
Index(['Commodity Derivative Name\n(including associated contracts)',
       'Venue MIC ', 'Name of Trading Venue ', 'Venue Product Codes ',
       'Principal Venue Product Code', 'Spot month single limit#',
       'Other month limit#', 'Conversion Factor', 'Unit of measurement',
       'Definition of spot month', 'Unnamed: 10', 'Unnamed: 11', 'Unnamed: 12',
       'Unnamed: 13', 'Unnamed: 14', 'Unnamed: 15'],
      dtype='object')
```

I have looked at a few solutions for this, and I am not sure if it is because I am tired, but I cannot get this to work at all.

I guess I could hardcode in the columns but the file could change in the future and thought this would be better to do. I think that maybe after it strips the column in the temp column, it is maybe looking for the unstripped column which is no longer there, so it bugs out - not completely sure.

I have the following code to clean the columns of a df:

```
f = pd.read_excel(r"fca_position_limits.xlsx")

# unwanted spaces need to be removed from headers
f.columns = f.columns.strip() # --> this did not work

temp_f = f.copy()

for column in f.columns:
    temp_f = temp_f[column].str.strip()
    if column[0:7] == "Unnamed":
        temp_f.drop(column, inplace=True)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To remove the trailing spaces:

```
df.columns = [c.strip() for c in df.columns]
```

and to drop the "Unnamed" columns:

```
df.drop(columns=df.filter(like='Unnamed').columns)
```

Here is an example for the `drop` part:

input:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame([], columns=['A', 'B', 'Unnamed 1', 'Unnamed 2', 'C'])
>>> df.columns
['A', 'B', 'Unnamed 1', 'Unnamed 2', 'C']
```

output:

```
>>> df2 = df.drop(columns=df.filter(like='Unnamed').columns)
>>> df2.columns
['A', 'B', 'C']
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked.
Would you mind explaining why mine didn't work? Would really help.

I also thought that the strip method needs to be assigned to a variable, otherwise the effect goes, or am I wrong on that as well?

Comment: Well, `df.columns` has not `strip` method. The `c.strip()` is saved in the list comprehension (and then in the `df.columns`).

Comment: btw, the dropping line of code didn't work for me. I used:
`for column in f.columns:
    if column[0:7] == "Unnamed":
        f.drop(column, inplace=True, axis=1`

which ended up working for me.

Comment: @Bamir have you saved the output in `df`? or used `df.drop(..., inplace=True)`? If this worked with your loop this should work in one shot.

Comment: I tried a loop with `for column in f.columns:
    f.drop(columns=f.filter(like='Unnamed').columns)` and also just  `f.drop(columns=f.filter(like='Unnamed').columns)` without it in a loop. Are you saying I should have done something like this: `f.columns = f.drop(columns=f.filter(like='Unnamed').columns)`?

Comment: @Bamir I provided an example